# Why are new kernel versions not appearing in Grub?

Tags: fedora, package-management, grub2

For the past few weeks, I thought my Fedora 38 installation wasn't getting kernel updates (I am running `6.2.15-300.fc38.x86_64`), but today I saw it install a kernel update (6.3.5) seemingly successfully, then rebooted to see that it still wasn't listing that version of the kernel in Grub. Based on the contents of `/boot`, it looks like this has been happening for some time - I also have Kernel 6.3.4 installed. Interestingly, I could not see a file for Kernel 6.2.15.

I tried running `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` manually, but encountered the following error:

```
/usr/bin/grub2-editenv: error: cannot open `/boot/grub2/grubenv.new': No such file or directory.
Generating grub configuration file ...
/usr/bin/grub2-editenv: error: cannot open `/boot/grub2/grubenv.new': No such file or directory.
```

It appears that the `/boot/grub2` directory does not exist in my system.

Obviously, having a partially-missing configuration for Grub is concerning, but it begs the question: how have I been able to boot and use my system normally for weeks on end without Grub having a configuration?

But more importantly, how can I fix this such that I can have the latest kernel versions listed within Grub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! It turns out that my system wasn't mounting the boot partition correctly - there was no entry for it in `/etc/fstab`. As such, after my laptop booted, it would create a `/boot` directory on my root partition, leading to new kernels being installed there instead of the boot partition. Here were the steps I took to fix it:

1. Edit `/etc/fstab` to mount `/dev/nvme1n1p2` as `/boot`
2. Remount all the fstab entries by running `sudo mount -a`
3. Reinstall the kernel by running `sudo dnf reinstall kernel-core`, since this adds the entry to Grub
4. Add back my boot entry for Windows by running `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` (the previous command seemed to erase it)
5. Reboot and choose the new kernel

Comment: Any mounted non-root filesystem needs a directory on the "parent" filesystem, that will act as a mount point. So the empty `/boot` directory most likely already existed on your root filesystem, intended as a mount point for the `/boot` filesystem.